# How to use Android SOAP Webservice Call

Tags: android, soap, ksoap, android-webservice

I am having a lot of trouble finding good information on how to call a standard SOAP web service in Android. any help

Comment: What trouble you are getting ?

Comment: am not getting any trouble, i don't have any idea how to use SOAP?

Comment: have you [googled it](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kusBU86GBOrV8gfQs4GQDQ#q=Android%2BSoap+Example) ?

Comment: yes i but am not getting better inofrmation about it

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to call SOAP web service from Android using **NTLM AUTHENTICATION**.

```
  SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject("urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customercard","Read");

    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);

    propinfo = new PropertyInfo();
    propinfo.setName("No");
    propinfo.setValue(no);
    propinfo.setType(no.getClass());
    propinfo.setNamespace("urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customercard");
    soapReq.addProperty(propinfo);


    NtlmTransport ntlm = new NtlmTransport(url, userid, password, domainname,systemname);
    try{
        if (headers!=null){
            ntlm.call("urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customercard/Read", soapEnvelope,headers);
        }else{
            ntlm.call("urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customercard/Read", soapEnvelope);
        }
        Object retObj = soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        if (retObj instanceof SoapFault){
            SoapFault fault = (SoapFault)retObj;
            Exception ex = new Exception(fault.faultstring);
            if (eventHandler != null)
                eventHandler.Wsdl2CodeFinishedWithException(ex);
        }else{
            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)retObj;
            if (result.getPropertyCount() > 0){
                System.out.println("RESULT 2"+result);
                Object obj = result.getProperty(0);
                SoapObject j = (SoapObject)obj;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should call a web service through a AsyncTask.
You must have a bean class and add internet permission in your manifest file. 
Check [this Example](http://andygeeks.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-get-data-from-soap-webservice.html) for your reference